How do I filter my system.array with where-object
I thought this would be straightforward, just filtering my array, smh.
$serverEnv.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                 
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                 
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array                                                             


# This is what I'm getting
ComputerName Env 
------------ --- 
server1      PROD
server1           
server2      PROD
     
    
# I'm trying  to get all servers that don't have a null or empty Env 

ComputerName Env 
------------ --- 
server1      PROD         
server2      PROD


# Tried this, but getting the ssame list with the blank Env records
$serverEnv | where-object { $_.Env -ne $null -or $_.Env -ne "" }


I thought this should be a straightforward question, but how is your $serverEnv defined?

$serverEnv | Where-Object { -not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.Env) } ?

-and not -or

Besides, $null should be at the left-hand-side of the operator (is $serverEnv.Env always a scalar or possibly an embedded array? What exactly is in: $serverEnv | ConvertTo-Json?)

$serverEnv | where-object Env automatically tests for the Env property to be not null or empty string.

It's a logic problem.  -and, not -or ($_.env -eq "" in this case) (beware of arrays on the left side of -ne):
$serverenv = 'computername,env
server1,prod
server1,
server2,prod' | convertfrom-csv 

$serverenv | where-object { $_.Env -ne $null -or $_.Env -ne "" }

computername env
------------ ---
server1      prod
server1
server2      prod


$serverenv | where-object { $_.Env -ne $null -and $_.Env -ne "" }

computername env
------------ ---
server1      prod
server2      prod

You could put a list on the left:
$serverenv | where-object { $null,"" -ne $_.env }

computername env
------------ ---
server1      prod
server2      prod


I was trying backquote zero, but that seems the same as empty space.
"`0" -eq ''

True


$serverEnv | where-object { $_.env -ne $null -and $_.env -ne "" }  this doesn't work but your where-object { $null,"" -ne $_.env } does

@SantiagoSquarzon works too

What is the character then, a space?

Maybe try $serverenv[1].env | format-hex
